# Careers.SE modal stays open when navigating back in iPhone

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Was browsing the desktop version of the Careers site on my iphone and noticed if you drill into a job and select Apply to display the modal but then navigate to the previous page the modal stays open over the previous page.

> [image]

Comment: Can't reproduce with Safari 7. What browser are you using? What iOS?

Comment: 7.1.2 iphone 5.  Chrome

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this using Chrome 37 running on Android 4.4.4.

Comment: Weird. iOS 7, iPhone 4S, Chrome 37 and can't reproduce.

Comment: Looking into it right now, will get back later today(ish)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your report! We were not closing the modal on popstate, which has now been fixed (funny thing, I was able to repro it on all browsers, for both desktop and mobile versions oO).

Should be working fine after the next push, 15 min or so.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]?